How can i put a date string in the body of a web request using Powershell?
I have a body of a web request in powershell like the following
  $body = "timePeriod":{"from":"2024-07-01T00:00:00+00:00","to":"2024-07-31T23:59:59+00:00"}}

How can i get the current month and the number of days in the month into some sort of variable  and replace the dates in the body string with those variables .
So i get something like
$body = "timePeriod":{"from":$startDate,"to":$endDate}}

But the date must be of that format , ie "2024-07-01T00:00:00+00:00"
I dont know exactly how to start to put a variable in there. Do i need to just concat to the string ?
How can i do this ?

Have you checked the Get-Date cmdlet bound with the -Format parameter ?

You can get a [datetime] instance describing the current moment in time from Get-Date - this will give us the current year and month, after which we can calculate the start and end dates:
$nowUTC = Get-Date |ForEach-Object ToUniversalTime

# construct [datetime] value describing the start of the month
$start = Get-Date -Year $nowUTC.Year -Month $nowUTC.Month -Day 1 |ForEach-Object Date
# advancing the value 1 month lands us on the start of the next month
$end = $start.AddMonths(1).AddMinutes(-1)

Now that we have the correct timestamps stored in variables, we just need to construct the JSON document and embed them with the correct format.
For formatting date/time strings I like to use the -f string format operator. To construct the JSON document we can construct a custom object and then pipe it to ConvertTo-Json at the end:
$json = [pscustomobject]@{
  timePeriod = [pscustomobject]@{
    from = '{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00}' -f $start
    to = '{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00}' -f $end
  }
} |ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$json now contains the desired string
